# Why is Emacs org-mode missing one date from clocktable?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have used Emacs' org-mode for a long time to keep track of my hours, and for whatever reason, the following snippet drawn from my actual org-mode file, consistently misreports both Saturday the 11th, and Sunday the 12th.

Looking into it, I find that the hours for Saturday and Sunday are combined into the Saturday entry, at least in the first clocktable.  In the second clocktable, which I specifically limited to the dates shown in the logbook, the hours are properly separated out.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could explain what's wrong, as I've never had this happen before, and I really do depend on it for timesheets!

**Things Tried**
* Re-compiled Emacs 25.1.1 .. just in case a library change was the issue.
* Used 'Packages' to upgrade everything.
* Locally compiled 'git' 2.x since 'magit' was complaining when I updated Packages.

Thanks!

```
Emacs Version...: GNU Emacs 25.1.1 - Locally compiled.
Org Version.....: 20170210         - Installed via 'Packages'
Operating System: CentOS 7         - From DVD early this year,
                                     and updated as needed.

* FOO
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2017-03-13 Mon 10:22]--[2017-03-13 Mon 19:17] =>  8:55
CLOCK: [2017-03-12 Sun 18:35]--[2017-03-12 Sun 19:17] =>  0:42
CLOCK: [2017-03-12 Sun 15:29]--[2017-03-12 Sun 16:23] =>  0:54
CLOCK: [2017-03-12 Sun 10:34]--[2017-03-12 Sun 11:18] =>  0:44
CLOCK: [2017-03-11 Sat 20:06]--[2017-03-11 Sat 22:59] =>  2:53
CLOCK: [2017-03-11 Sat 15:09]--[2017-03-11 Sat 19:15] =>  4:06
CLOCK: [2017-03-11 Sat 11:56]--[2017-03-11 Sat 12:32] =>  0:36
CLOCK: [2017-03-11 Sat 11:40]--[2017-03-11 Sat 11:56] =>  0:16
CLOCK: [2017-03-10 Fri 12:26]--[2017-03-10 Fri 20:10] =>  7:44
:LOGBOOK:

** WHERE DID SUNDAY THE 12TH GO?
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 9 :scope file :step day :tstart "<-1w>" :tend "<+1d>"

Daily report: [2017-03-07 Tue]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0.00* |

Daily report: [2017-03-08 Wed]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0.00* |

Daily report: [2017-03-09 Thu]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0.00* |

Daily report: [2017-03-10 Fri]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *7.73* |
|--------------+--------|
| FOO          | 7.73   |

Daily report: [2017-03-11 Sat]
| Headline     | Time    |
|--------------+---------|
| *Total time* | *10.18* |
|--------------+---------|
| FOO          | 10.18   |

Daily report: [2017-03-13 Mon]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *8.92* |
|--------------+--------|
| FOO          | 8.92   |

Daily report: [2017-03-14 Tue]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0.00* |

Daily report: [2017-03-15 Wed]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0.00* |
#+END:

** OH HERE IT IS?  BUT WHY?
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 9 :scope file :step day :tstart "<2017-03-10>" :tend "<2017-03-14>"

Daily report: [2017-03-10 Fri]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *7.73* |
|--------------+--------|
| FOO          | 7.73   |

Daily report: [2017-03-11 Sat]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *7.85* |
|--------------+--------|
| FOO          | 7.85   |

Daily report: [2017-03-12 Sun]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *2.33* |
|--------------+--------|
| FOO          | 2.33   |

Daily report: [2017-03-13 Mon]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *8.92* |
|--------------+--------|
| FOO          | 8.92   |
#+END:
```

Comment: Good question! I wonder if it has something to do with the change to DST this past weekend in the US. Stepping through `org-clocktable-steps` certainly jumps from Sat. to Mon in the first test. Shifting the clock dates one week forward and changing the `:tstart` to <+1d> and the `:tend` to <+1w> does not exhibit the problem. Not sure why the problem does not appear in  the second test though: I haven't traced that yet.

Comment: (smacks forehead) DST... I never thought about DST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar problem (for November 2018) and have reported it to `emacs-orgmode@gnu.org`